# Django why does my null boolean field save as True in my SQL table?

Tags: django, forms, null, boolean

Here's what's in my models.py:

```
class GraduationApp(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    addr_to_photographer = models.NullBooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'graduation_app'
```

Here's what's in my forms.py:

```
BOOLEAN_CHOICES = (
               (None,' '),
               (True,'Yes'),
               (False,'No')
               )
class EnterAppForm(ModelForm):
    addr_to_photographer = forms.ChoiceField(choices=BOOLEAN_CHOICES, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = GraduationApp
        fields=('addr_to_photographer')
```

Here's what's in my template:

```
Address to Photographer? {{ form.addr_to_photographer }}
```

Here's my save in the views.py:

```
print 'your POST address_to_photographer is', request.POST['addr_to_photographer']
print 'your form.cleaned_data addr_to_photographer is', form.cleaned_data['addr_to_photographer']
updapp = GraduationAppForm.objects.get(id=request.POST['app_id'])
updapp.addr_to_photographer = form.cleaned_data['addr_to_photographer']
updapp.save()
print 'YOU JUST UPDATED ME', updapp.person.eid, 'ADDR TO PHOTO IS', updapp.addr_to_photographer
```

I am getting these print statements:

**your POST address_to_photographer is False**

**your form.cleaned_data addr_to_photographer is False**

**YOU JUST UPDATED ME oy278 ADDR TO PHOTO IS (u'False',)**

But when I go look at the field in MySQL, it has a 1 in it, instead of a 0.
HELP!

Comment: Shouldn't you set `choices=BOOLEAN_CHOICES` on the model?

Comment: What seems weird is that `(u'False',)` in the last `print` statement is a tuple with unicode inside. Odd!

Comment: Try this: `updapp.addr_to_photographer = bool(form.cleaned_data['addr_to_photographer'])`

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you move the choices to model field definition?
You could skip the repeative field declaration in forms:

models.py:

```
BOOLEAN_CHOICES = (
    (None,' '),
    (True,'Yes'),
    (False,'No')
)

class GraduationApp(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    addr_to_photographer = models.NullBooleanField(choices=BOOLEAN_CHOICES, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'graduation_app'
```

forms.py:

```
class EnterAppForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GraduationApp
```

Comment: I tried putting bool around it
    updapp.addr_to_photographer = bool(form.cleaned_data['addr_to_photographer'])

and I got back: your POST address_to_photographer is False
your form.cleaned_data addr_to_photographer is False
YOU JUST UPDATEDDDD ME helen ADDR TO PHOTO IS (True,)

The only thing I have to say about that is that at least the thing is telling me what it REALLY saved (True)--however, since I tried to save False, I don't know if this is better or not?

Comment: What is bugging me so much--and what makes me think there is some fundamental problem with my setup--is that I would have thought django forms would have solved all of this for me.  For one thing, before I added BOOLEAN_CHOICES to the form, it was rendering as a dropdown with something like Unknown, Yes, and No as my options.  Behind the scenes, the values were 1, 2, and 3--it seemed to me that that would NEVER store 0, 1, or '' as my values, so I tried both 0, 1, and '' AND True, False, and None behind the scenes, but they don't work, either :P.

Answer (score 0):

THE SOLUTION WAS THIS: when updating, I needed to get the intance of my record that I needed to update, and then I needed to populate my form with my post data AND reference the instance of my record.

```
updapp = GraduationApp.objects.get(id=request.POST['app_id'])
form = EnterAppForm(request.POST,instance=updapp)
```

I actually did not need anything in my forms.py except this:

```
class EnterAppForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = GraduationApp
        fields=('status','name_in_pgm','addr_to_photographer','paper_form_reason_1','paper_form_reason_2','notes',\
            'transfer_work_on_transcript','cbe_work_on_transcript','enrolled_other_institution',\
            'enrolled_correspondence','getting_degree_other_ut_college','understand_min_gpa_req',\
            'understand_no_drop_req','understand_pass_fail_req','understand_deg_requirements',\
            'address_verified','eligibility_confirmed','placement_survey_complete')
```